# Footer keeps overlapping with the page's content

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

For whatever reason, my footer is refusing to stay at the bottom of the page and not overlap with the page's content. It'll go to like, near the bottom but it still overlaps. It also won't apply a background color which is really strange. I've tried a bunch of different things but nothing seems to work. Here is the html.

```
<body>

 <div class="container">

<div id=footer>
<div id=help><h8> How Can Help?</h8>
<p>Customer Service</p>
<p>Track My Order </p>
<p>Customer Service Twitter</p>
<p>Size Guide</p>
<p>Returns</p>
</div>

<div id=app><h8> Get The App</h8><br>
  <a href="https://www.apple.com/ios/app-store/">
  <img border="0" alt="App Store" src="img/app.png" width="160" height="100">
  </a>
</div>

<div id=aboutus><h8> About Us </h8>
<p></p>
<p>About District Apparel</p>
<p>Careers</p>
<p>Become An Affiliate</p>
</div>

<div id=email><h8>Get Exclusive Offers & Updates</h8><br>
  <form>
    Sign Up
      <input type="text" name="firstname">
</form>
</div>

</div>
</div>

</body>
```

and here is the css

```
/* Footer */

#container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #5D5C61;
}

#footer {
    background-color: #5D5C61;
    font-size: 7px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    word-spacing: 3px;
  bottom: 0px;
    height: 300px;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  clear: both;
    left: 0;
    min-width:100%;
        }

#help {
    float: left;
    font-size: 15px;
    width:25%;
    bottom:0;

    }

#aboutus {
    float: left;
    width:25%;
    font-size: 15px;
    bottom:0;
    }

#app {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 15px;
  bottom:0;
  }

  #email {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    font-size: 15px;
    bottom:0;
    }
```

Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you forget to clear the floats?

Answer (score 0):

First I got rid of all your `position:sticky` code, that doesn't work for sticky footers. Next, at the top of the CSS code I made the container 100% height with `display:flex` and `flex-flow:column` to make the layout of the page work like a vertically aligned flexbox. The final step was to give the footer a `margin-top:auto`, which in flexbox means it will always push itself to the very bottom of the viewport:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:column;
}

#footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}


/* Footer */

#footer {
  background-color: #5D5C61;
  font-size: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  word-spacing: 3px;
  height: 300px;
}

#help {
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
}

#aboutus {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 15px;
  bottom: 0;
}

#app {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 15px;
  bottom: 0;
}

#email {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 15px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div id=footer>
    <div id=help>
      <h8> How Can Help?</h8>
      <p>Customer Service</p>
      <p>Track My Order </p>
      <p>Customer Service Twitter</p>
      <p>Size Guide</p>
      <p>Returns</p>
    </div>

    <div id=app>
      <h8> Get The App</h8><br>
      <a href="https://www.apple.com/ios/app-store/">
        <img border="0" alt="App Store" src="img/app.png" width="160" height="100">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id=aboutus>
      <h8> About Us </h8>
      <p></p>
      <p>About District Apparel</p>
      <p>Careers</p>
      <p>Become An Affiliate</p>
    </div>

    <div id=email>
      <h8>Get Exclusive Offers & Updates</h8><br>
      <form>
        Sign Up
        <input type="text" name="firstname">
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

yo so i just did

```
#footer {
    background-color: #5D5C61;
    font-size: 7px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    word-spacing: 3px;
  bottom: 0px;
    height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  clear: both;
    left: 0;
    min-width:100%;
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fke46qno/

Comment: really don't know why u need a sticky position ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want a short and simple solution for a footer fixed at the bottom of the page, you can use this:

```
#footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
```

This always works for me :)